# Obtain a table of non-uniformly-distributed random 0 and 1 draws

Tags: tables, pgfmath, random-numbers

I wish to produce a `n x m` matrix of randomly-drawn 0s and 1s, in which draws are fresh with each compilation. So far, I have achieved this with the following code for a `15 x 10` table.

However, 0s and 1s are each drawn each time with probability `p=0.5`. I would like to be able to input any `p`. How can I do this?

I would also be grateful for a less clunky way to input/change the number of rows and columns of this table/matrix.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}

\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000} % fresh draws with each comile
\newcommand{\Rand}{\pgfmathparse{int(random(2)-1)}\pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand \\
    \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand & \Rand 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p=0.5` is equal to there is `1` in `2`. So I can say `p=m/n` which means there is `m` in `n`. Then it is easy to use `\int_rand:n {<number (here is n)>}` in `expl3` to get a pseudo-random number between `1` and `n`. If the random number is greater than `m`, output `1` otherwise output `0`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\Rand} { O{1} O{2} } {
  \int_compare:nTF {\int_rand:n {#2} <= #1}{0}{1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
  \AutoNiceMatrix{15-10}{\Rand}
  \mskip 100mu
  \AutoNiceMatrix{15-10}{\Rand[1][10]}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Random matrix with tikz

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\Rand} { O{1} O{2} } {
  \int_compare:nTF {\int_rand:n {#2} <= #1}{0}{1}
}
\tl_new:N \l__rand_matrix_body_tl
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548881/201158 @egrep
\NewDocumentCommand {\RandMatrix} { O{} D(){matrix} m m O{1} O{2} } {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_clear:N \l__rand_matrix_body_tl
  \int_step_inline:nn {#3} {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__rand_matrix_body_tl {\use_none:n}
    \int_step_inline:nn {#4} {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__rand_matrix_body_tl {
        \pgfmatrixnextcell \Rand[#5][#6]
      }
    }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__rand_matrix_body_tl {\\}
  }
  \matrix [#1] (#2) {\tl_use:N \l__rand_matrix_body_tl};
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \RandMatrix[matrix of nodes, draw, row 1 column 1/.style=red](a){15}{10}
  \RandMatrix[matrix of nodes, right=of a, row 1 column 3/.style=red](b){15}{10}[1][10]
  \node [above=1em of a] {$p=0.5$};
  \node [above=1em of b] {$p=0.1$};
  \draw [->] (a-1-1) edge [bend left=20] (b-1-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's nice. Is there a way to make it work as `\documentclass{standalone}`?

Comment: @monkey-dart Now you have a tikz command.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `sagetex` solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
import numpy as np
def randbin(M,N,P):
    return np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(M,N), p=[P, 1-P])

matrixA = latex(matrix(randbin(15,10,.5)))
A = matrixA[6:-7]
\end{sagesilent}
\noindent
$\sagestr{A}$
\end{document}
```

I found the code to construct the numpy array in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065941/create-binary-random-matrix-with-probability-in-python?rq=1) and fixed it up. The function `randbin(M,N,P)` will create a numpy array of order m by n where the probability of an entry being 0 is P. Printing that result would look ugly as it would be in a form like [[0,1,0],[0,1,1]...]. I take that numpy array and create the latex code for its matrix with the line `matrixA = latex(matrix(randbin(15,10,.5)))`. From the documentation [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/latex.html) I know that the matrix will start with `\left(` and end with `\right)`, so I remove that from the string with `A = matrixA[6:-7]`. This gives me the numbers in an array. The result running in Cocalc is shown below:

[image]

Notice from the picture that, under the array of zeros and ones is a button to `Build` and a button to `Force Build`. Using the `Force Build` button will recompile and change the numbers, while 'Build` will recompile without changing the numbers. By changing the values of M, N, and P to 25, 25, and .25 you can quickly create another array:

[image]

The final observation to make is in the second picture. It says `Build Control and Log` where the buttons to `Build` and `Force Build` were. Clicking on `Build Control and Log` will get the 2 buttons back.

I just noticed your comment about making the code work with `standalone`. That's easily done, too. Here is the output:

[image]

**EDIT:** I need to add that Sage, the computer algebra system that makes things run, can either be downloaded and installed on your computer or accessed with a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account. It's simple and you can be up and running in a couple of minutes. Installing Sage on your computer is more problematic. Documentation on the `sagetex` package is [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex).